# Access my web applications in PHP/APACHE without change host files

Tags: php, apache, web-applications, xampp, hosts-file

I work with Apache that is installed in a Windows Server(Windows Server 2012 R2) , so i have my web applications in the htdocs folder (in the server ofc) if i want to access the applications via other computers connected to the server i have to change each host file in each pc...

If you work with 2, 3 pc that is ok, however when you have at least 40 pc's it can be very tiring.

That's way i'm asking this question.

I mean,it's possible to simply put the url in the browser and the computers connected to the server enter in my web application?

Comment: Can't you just access it via the IP address? Or else make a temporary DNS record for a subdomain?

Comment: you need to define alias? is it clean apache or its coming with xamp wamp??

Comment: @Zeljka Sorry , its coming with X.A.M.P.P

Comment: @jrswgtr i can access via IP address, the problem is , I have several web applications with different URL, and if i use IP address it can only encounter the first web application we made.

Comment: @nuno1197 I will write answer with code below

Answer (score 0):

This isn't maybe the best solution, but here it is
in file `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf`

Inside `<IfModule alias_module>` write following lines

```
Alias / "C:\xampp\htdocs"
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
    AllowOverride all
    Order deny,allow
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Later restart apache and try to access you applications with inside the same `intranet` `network`:

```
computer-name/app-folder/
```

In general this isn't the best solution because you are exposing entire root folder `htdocs`, also I would suggest to you to move you application from `htdocs` and define application in `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. You can create aliases for application outside `htdocs` folder which are defined in `httpd-vhosts.conf`